# How to handle all Screen Orientations in ios 6.0?

Tags: iphone, ios6, screen-orientation

I am using the following two methods:

```
-(Bool)shouldAutorotate

{

return YES;

}

-(NSUInteger)supportedInterfaceOrientations

{

return UIInterfaceOrienationsMaskAll;

}
```

and in TARGETS there is Supported Interface Orientations,i have selected all orientations Portrait,Upside Down,Landscape Left,Landscape Right.

And i am not using any tab bar or navigation application.
It is simple a **UiViewController**.
And in AppDelegate i am using

```
self.window.rootViewController=self.viewController;
```

but the problem is that when i am doing this my View doesn't come on its exact place.it got disturb here and there,not occupying exact position in landscape and Portrait Mode.

In which method i have to write code so that it occupies exact position in **Ipad**.

Answer (score 0):

You will have to set any autoresizing or autolayout properties in interface builder to make things stretch and re-size on rotation, assuming you have set your UI that way.

Or in your code, you can implement the `willAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:` method as well in order to programmatically set the positions of UI elements before a rotation occurs.  Alternatively, I believe `UIView` has an `autoResizingMask` property which can be set to handle layout changes. There are several ways of going about this - you just need to find which way works best for your implementation needs!